# Making a leaderboard out of a List - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Predict List contains Maps. Every Map has a username and predictPoints. On the bases of Predict Points I want to display a Rank List aka Leaderboard. To tackle the same points rank problem I converted the list to sets but now the Function is returning an int after counting the sets. 0 to 1 to 3 to 5. Please refer the Code and image for reference.
Observation: It's returning rank after counting the same number sets.

Code:

```
// Sorting List
void sortingList() {
        predictRankList.sort(
            (a, b) => ((b['predictpoints']).compareTo(a['predictpoints'])));
}

 // FN Returns Rank No. for Predict List
  int exPredictRankNumber(int index) => predictRankList
      .where((element) =>
          element['predictpoints'] > predictRankList[index]['predictpoints'])
      .toSet()
      .length;

// UI
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: _rankController.predictRankList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  // Rank
                  leading: Text(
                    _rankController.exPredictRankNumber(index).toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),

                  // Country & Username
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        // Country
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                          child: Text(
                            _rankController.returnFlagEmoji(index: index) ==
                                    'null'
                                ? ''
                                : _rankController.returnFlagEmoji(index: index),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                        // Username
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
                          child: Text(
                            '${_rankController.predictRankList[index]['username']}',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                  // Points
                  trailing: Text(
                    '${_rankController.predictRankList[index]['predictpoints']}',
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: Make it a list, sort it, and then rank = index + 1.

Comment: I already sorted the list. Sorry for not including it. @HTMHell

Comment: I think you need to change the sort from (b to a) to (a to b)

Comment: No. That will reverse the list. @MousaAlribi

Comment: try this. create new list and assign your sorted list to this new list , and pass this new sorted list in listview.